# I am new in reactjs and when i was trying to run my first react js project it showing error, it's showing error just after the setup

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

[these error are showing when i was try to run my first react project. I don't know how to fix please help.][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acb0i.pngstrong text

Comment: Give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: Can you please add more details. Have you written some code yet, or this happened right after project setup?

Comment: it happen just after the set up

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was another instance was running. Search for other react instance running and kill it. It should resume properly after.
Or this is happening because nothing is listening on your adresse:port